# CachingHttpClient not consuming backend HttpResponse entity cause app to freeze

Tags: android, httpclient

I'm using HttpClient 4.2.1 with a PoolingClientConnectionManager and I have discovered that my app will start to hang trying to acquire http connections after some use.  This symptom seems to be a common mistake if you fail to consume the HttpEntity since 4.2.1 relies on the closing of the Content's stream to return it the connection to the pool.

Here's how I'm assembling the HttpClients and their pool

```
HttpClient standardClient = null;
HttpClient cachedClient = null;
PoolingClientConnectionManager connectionManager = null;

protected synchronized HttpClient getStandardClient() {
  if ( standardClient == null ) {
    connectionManager = new PoolingClientConnectionManager();
    connectionManager.setMaxTotal(2);
    connectionManager.closeIdleConnections(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    standardClient = new DecompressingHttpClient( new DefaultHttpClient (connectionManager));
    Log.i(tag, "Creating ConnectionManager and standard http client");
  }

  return standardClient;
}

protected synchronized HttpClient getCachedClient() {
  if ( cachedClient == null ) {
    CacheConfig cacheConfig = new CacheConfig();
    cacheConfig.setMaxObjectSize( 512*1024 );
    cacheConfig.setMaxCacheEntries( 10 );

    cachedClient = new CachingHttpClient(getStandardClient(),
                                         getCacheStorage(),
                                         cacheConfig);
    Log.i(tag, "Creating CachingHttpClient");
  }

  return cachedClient;
}
```

As you can see I have two clients.  A caching http client that wraps the standard client.

Now what I've found is that if I remove cachedClient and only use standardClient, I don't have any issues with the pool hanging and orphaned connections.

Looking through the source code for CachingHttpClient it doesn't appear to consume the underlying entity.  Has anyone else experienced this?

Can anyone see any bugs in my code and how I've configured and used HttpClient?  Does anyone know of anything I can do in my code to properly get the backend entity to get consumed properly?

Btw, here's how I use the http clients and consume them...

```
HttpClient httpClient = cacheOkay ? getCachedClient() : getStandardClient();  
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request, localContext);
HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();  

int responseStatus = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

byte[] responseBody = EntityUtils.toByteArray(resEntity);
EntityUtils.consume(resEntity);
```

Also, for those wondering this is on Android and I've used JarJar to repackage HttpClient 4.2.1 to an alternate package structure so it doesn't conflict with the older HttpClient classes that ship with Android.  But despite the repackaging the code is 100% 4.2.1.  I just mention this to avoid any suggestion of conflict in running HttpClient 4.2.1 on Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after wrestling with this I feel pretty convinced that this is a bug in HttpCommons.  The bug appears to be that HttpCachingClient doesn't properly consume the HttpEntity from the backend HttpClient.  In our case, since this a pooled client, this prevents the connections from every returning to the pool.

My working around was to make sure HttpCachingClient closes the stream from the backend client.

Here's the revised code for creating the caching client

```
    protected synchronized HttpClient getCachedClient() {
      if ( cachedClient == null ) {
        CacheConfig cacheConfig = new CacheConfig();
        cacheConfig.setMaxObjectSize( 512*1024 );
        cacheConfig.setMaxCacheEntries( 10 );
        cachedClient = new CachingHttpClient(getStandardClient(),
                                             new HeapResourceFactory() {
                                               @Override
                                               public Resource generate(String requestId,InputStream instream,InputLimit limit) throws IOException {
                                                    try {
                                                      return super.generate(requestId, instream, limit);
                                                    }
                                                    finally {
                                                      instream.close();
                                                    }
                                                }
                                             },
                                             application.getCacheStorage(),
                                             application.getCacheConfig());
        Log.i(tag, "Creating CachingHttpClient");
    }

    return cachedClient;
}
```

So basically I subclassed the HeapResourceFactory and added the instream.close() to make sure it consumes that backend entity.